# Pytorch: Trained using DataParallel and Testing on cpu

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I have a trained model using one of my other pre-trained model in pytorch. For testing, I would like to test on cpu rather than gpu. The problem is that since I have used Dataparallel function during training, it is not straight forward for me to convert it to cpu.

My code for trained model is as follow:

```
class DGCNN_tl(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(DGCNN_tl, self).__init__()
        self.model = DGCNN()
        if torch.cuda.device_count() > 1:
            print(str(torch.cuda.device_count())+" GPUs detected!")
            self.model = nn.DataParallel(self.model)
            patch_replication_callback(self.model) #sync_batch_norm
            self.model.to(device)
        self.model.load_state_dict(torch.load("teeth_seg2_pretrained.pt"))
        
        for param in self.model.parameters(): #making all layers fine tuneable
            param.requires_grad = True
            
    def forward(self, inputs, l):
        outputs,t,feature = self.model(inputs, l)
        return outputs, t, feature
```

Below is how I tried to convert it to cpu for testing:

```
dgcnn_lower = DGCNN_tl()
# original saved file with DataParallel
model_old = torch.load('teeth_seg2_lower_0.953iou.pt', map_location=torch.device('cpu'))

# create new OrderedDict that does not contain `module.`
from collections import OrderedDict

new_state_dict = OrderedDict()
for k, v in model_old.items():
    name = k[7:] # remove `module.`
    new_state_dict[name] = v

# load params
dgcnn_lower.load_state_dict(new_state_dict)
```

This gives an error saying

```
    Missing key(s) in state_dict: "model.module.transform_net.bn1.weight", "model.module.transform_net.bn1.bias"
```

"teeth_seg2_pretrained.pt": This is my pre-trained model which was used to train my current model
"teeth_seg2_lower_0.953iou.pt": This is my current model which I would like to test it on cpu

Can somebody give me an advice or help to solve this problem?
Thank you!!

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I have the same issue.